# Groupby and lists category

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the follwing DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {"hours": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
"values": [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I have been trying to add an extra column to `df` including the values by groupby `values` and the follwing list:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 16, 18, 21, 23]
```

this list represents hours after which the gruoping should be conducted. E.g. in the new column `category` it gives 1 for those `values` between 2 and 4 gives 1 and else where gives 0 and for hours between 6 and 8 gives 2 where the values are 1 and else where 0  and so on..
I tried the following:

```
df.groupby(["values", "hours"])
```

and I could not come forward with it.

The expected result looks like:

[image]

Comment: why 21 is 5? It should be 4 right? `2, 4, => 1 ;6, 8,=> 2 ;10, 16, => 3 ;18, 21, => 4 ;23=> 5`

Comment: 5 is just the category to distinguish all times from each other, e.g. 2 to 4 category 1, 6 to 8 category 2, 10 stands alone category 3, 16 to 18 category 4 and 21 to 23 category 5. Does that help?

Answer (score 1):

Updated to answer question. You'd have to create individual queries (as below). This should work for the specific ranges

```
df['category'] = 0
df.loc[(df['hours'] >= 2) & (df['hours'] <= 4), 'category'] = df['values']
df.loc[(df['hours'] >= 6) & (df['hours'] <= 8), 'category'] = df['values'] * 2
df.loc[df['hours'] == 10, 'category'] = df['values'] * 3
df.loc[(df['hours'] >= 16) & (df['hours'] <= 18), 'category'] = df['values'] * 4
df.loc[(df['hours'] >= 21) & (df['hours'] <= 23), 'category'] = df['values'] * 5
```

Comment: if it would be randomly (not every 5 hours) what should be replaced instead of 5?

Comment: I have updated my answer to account for this. Thanks for the clarification @DaveWill

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your question So I will assume what Epsi95 has commented. So you can try something like this:

This will work when you have list having even size. You can modify this for your case also.

```
df['category']=0
x = list(zip(bins[::2], bins[1::2]))
rng = { range(i[0], i[1]+1):idx+1 for idx,i in enumerate(x)}
df.loc[df['values'].eq(1), 'category'] = df.loc[df['values'].eq(1), 'hours'].apply(lambda x: next((v for k, v in rng.items() if x in k), 0))
```

### Edit:

```
df['category']=0

bins = [(2, 4), (6, 8), (10), (16, 18), (21, 23)]

rng = {}
for idx,i in enumerate(bins, start=1):
    if not isinstance(i, int):
        rng[range(i[0],i[1]+1)]=idx
    else:
        rng[i] = idx


def func(val):
    print(val)
    for k, v in rng.items():
        if isinstance(k, int):
            if val==k:
                return v
        else:
            if val in k:
                return v
        
df.loc[df['values'].eq(1), 'category'] = df.loc[df['values'].eq(1), 'hours'].apply(func)
```

---

**df:**

```
    hours   values  category
0   1   0   0
1   2   1   1
2   3   1   1
3   4   1   1
4   5   0   0
5   6   1   2
6   7   0   0
7   8   1   2
8   9   0   0
9   10  1   3
10  11  0   0
11  12  0   0
12  13  0   0
13  14  0   0
14  15  0   0
15  16  1   4
16  17  1   4
17  18  1   4
18  19  0   0
19  20  0   0
20  21  1   5
21  22  0   0
22  23  1   5
```

Comment: I tried to run it, it retunrs an error asking what is bins?

Comment: @DaveWill `bins = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 16, 18, 21, 23]`